# Delete file android - SDK 33

Tags: android, file, local-storage, filesystems, storage

Scenario: I've an app that donwloads a csv file that after processing I would like to delete from android Donwloads folder.

Problem: I can't delete the file.

Attempt 01:

```
        val rawFilePath = inputData.getString(FILE_PATH)
        val filePath = rawFilePath?.subSequence(7, rawFilePath.length).toString()

        val file = File(filePath)
        if (file.exists()) {
            val deleted = file.delete()

            logD("Deleted? $deleted")
        } else {
            logE("File do not exists")
        }
```

In this code I got a log "Deleted? false", so the file system finds the file, but do not delete.

Attempt 02:

```
        val downloadId = inputData.getLong(DOWNLOAD_ID, -1L)
        val uri: Uri = MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        logD("Path $uri.path")
        val selection = MediaStore.Downloads._ID + "=?"
        logD("selection $selection")
        val selectionArgs = arrayOf<String>(java.lang.String.valueOf(downloadId))

        logD("DONWLOAD ID: $downloadId")

        val deleteint = context.contentResolver.delete(uri, selection, selectionArgs)

        logD("status: $deleteint")
```

In this case I got the log like "status: 0", so the file is not being deleted as well.

This code donwloads my file and register a broadcast to wait until the donwload is finished:

```
    val basePath = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), DOWNLOAD)
    if (!basePath.exists()) {
        basePath.mkdirs()
    }

    path = basePath.absolutePath + "/" + season.code+season.period+".csv"

    EasyDownloadManager.startDowload(context, path, season.dataUrl)
    context.registerReceiver(downloadBroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE))
```

This is the class `EasyDownloadManager`

```
import android.app.DownloadManager
import android.content.Context
import android.net.Uri
import java.io.File
import java.io.InputStreamReader

object EasyDownloadManager {


fun startDowload(context: Context, downloadPath: String, url: String){

    val file = File(downloadPath)
    val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI)
    request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(file))
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)

    val downloadManager = context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    downloadManager.enqueue(request)
}

fun getFileFromId(context: Context, id: Long) : InputStreamReader {
    val downloadManager = context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    val uri: Uri = downloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(id)
    val inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
    val inputStreamReader = InputStreamReader(inputStream)

    return inputStreamReader
    }
}
```

These are my permissions on manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

These are my gradle file configs:

```
compileSdk 33

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.curuto.footballdata"
    minSdk 28
    targetSdk 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

And I'm sure the app has "Storage Permission", I'm running on an android 10

Comment: `Problem: I can't delete the app.` The file you mean. You should use a File instance with the same absolutePath() as with download. But we dont  see that you do. Please edit your post. And then use File.delete().

Comment: @blackapps I've tried use the same instance add an file but it did not worked. I've also printed the absolute path when I create the file and when I delete it, they match, but the file still is not being deleted. Any other ideas?

Comment: What is EasyDownloadManager? Use DownloadManager.

Comment: I have pasted my whole EasyDownloadManager class here, I'm using DownloadManager inside it

Comment: Can your app create a file in Download directory itself? And after that delete it?

Comment: Not only use File.exists() but also File.canWrite() and File.canRead().

Comment: Yes, I can create a file in the Downloads directory, I'm acctually donwloading a file from the internet, and storing it in Donwloads directory, and after processing its contents I want to delete it, so remove all files that will no be used in the future.

I also tried yet delete other files in that folder and I was not able to do it.

Comment: You talk too much and yet you did not answer all my simple questions. Dont tell what you want again. Just answer my questions. Confusing

Comment: `I'm acctually donwloading a file from the internet,` No. Your app is not doing that. Your app asked the DownloadManager to do it.

Comment: @blackapps your last comment make me figure out. I was lacking permissions indeed. I had opened the app settings and manually allowed stoage permission, but for some reason it was not enough, now i placed the permission request for storage when the user opens the app, and after accepting, it worked like a charm.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I've met an approximate problem when a update my app to targetsdk 33.
The problem was a file TRULY exist, but file.exist() returns false value. So the code won't run file.delete().